# Как правильно убить процесс средствами Winapi/C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите как корректно убить процесс средствами с++/winapi ?

По попутно есть так же вопрос можно ли занести список процессов и убить их?

Какой список используется?

Comment: убивание процесса не может быть корректным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убийство процессов считать корректным в принципе нельзя, т.к. Вы нарушаете привычный ход работы того или иного процесса. Но если уж очень нужно, то можно использовать функцию [`TerminateProcess()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess). По понятным причинам (C++ не работает с другими процессами) в C++ аналогов нет.

Чтобы уничтожить группу процессов, нужно получить идентификаторы нужных процессов и применить к ним вышеупомянутую функцию.

Comment: Благодарю, вот допустим я хочу сделать список нужных процессов куда мне их занести?

Comment: @InvertSOD, куда угодно. Можете, к примеру, `std::vector<HANDLE>` использовать.

Comment: Я был бы очень признателен если бы Вы мне предоставили пример занесения (пример) процессов в этот список, просто в интернете я такого не нашёл, или плохо искал.

Comment: @InvertSOD, задавайте отдельный вопрос. Только нормальный. Я не понимаю, в чём там проблема может быть с занесением, если Вы уже получаете идентификаторы процессов. Если не получаете, тогда так и спрашивайте. В общем, задавайте другой вопрос, в котором подробно опишите, что у Вас есть и что не получается.